# Can I code Jenkins pipeline stage view page to display git commit id?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Is there any way I can get the git commit id to show on the current row?

[image: Jenkins stage view page]

It doesn't even show when I click on the grey bit with the commits - no IDs

[image: Jenkins showing commits but no ID]

I have to click on the "See details" link - which is 2 clicks too many, according to my team mates who are addicted to commit hashes and spurn the use of human-readable version numbers.

Even worse, when there are no commits that haven't been built yet, that box with "2 commits" is just blank with no link and so no commit id at all.

Ideally someone knows of a way to do it with groovy in the Jenkinsfile.

I have already played around with `stage("Doing " + GIT_COMMIT_ID)` but that makes the cells in the table extra extra wide.

Is there some Jenkins-foo I can use?